# Reading a sequence of words to add them in a vector

Tags: c++, vector, cin

I recently bought a [C++ Primer](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321714113) and got stuck with a problem. I have to read a sequence of words using `cin` and store the values in a `vector`. After having unusual problems, I found out that `while(cin >> words)` invites problems (like infinite loop) if you expect invalid inputs: [Using cin to get user input](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/6046/)

```
int main()
{
    string words;
    vector<string> v;
    cout << "Enter words" << endl;
    while (cin >> words)
    {
        v.push_back(words);
    }
    for(auto b : v)
        cout << b << "  ";
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Therefore, I'm trying to find an alternative to this problem. Help ?

Comment: If you don't like the while loop, when do you expect it to end?

Comment: Perhaps you could put a condition inside of the `while` loop to `break` out of the loop if the condition is met.

Comment: If you don't expect invalid input you're being overly optimistic.

Comment: The while loop is supposed to end when it encounters an invalid input but that is the primary problem. If we supply an invalid input to `while(std::cin >> words)`, the loop becomes an infinite loop.

Comment: No, it doesn't. It stops looping. If this particular condition gives you an infinite loop, you're doing something else wrong.

Comment: @jrok
I've posted the code

Comment: @Caribou I've posted the code

Comment: @AyushAgarwal, With minimal additions to get it running, it works fine: http://liveworkspace.org/code/kzsl0%241. What counts as invalid?

Comment: You can always check the string in the body of the loop, see if it's valid (for your definition of valid) and then `break` out manualy if needed.

Comment: @chris If we have `while(std::value)` where value is an integer then inputs of any other type should be invalid. Similarly, any inputs except Strings should be invalid but the input accepts integers too and keeps running in the code that I posted

Comment: An 'integer' inputted by the user is a string.  If you want to determine what is and isn't a word, then you have to check the characters in each string entered and decide whether or not to put it in your vector.

Comment: @paddy I was trying to solve this question and I'm not sure what the 'invalid input' would be in this case. The authors of C++ Primer kept telling me that the lopp `while(std << word)` would stop as soon as you provide an invalid input. I tried writing 'while(getline(cin, words)) but that results in an infinite loop as well.

Comment: Oh, I see.  Well, there aren't really invalid inputs when it comes to strings.  What they probably mean is if the stream ends (such as end-of-file or some other error), but because you are inputting from `cin` there is no end-of-file (in linux you can cause `cin` to end by pressing Ctrl-D).

Comment: @paddy So what do you suggest ? I want to input words like 'abc', 'liberty', 'effect' and add them to the vector. And yeah, after inputting every word I press 'Enter' to continue with the input of the next word. I'm using NetBeans + GCC 4.7.2 by the way, if that helps

Comment: Then you can require the user to just press enter (*ie* an empty line) to finish adding words.  Then you can use the `getline` approach and stop looping when the user gives you an empty line.  The stream will still be valid, so you have to test for a zero-length string and then break from your loop.  I have added code to my answer.

Comment: @paddy I just added `if(words==" ")` after the while condition and now if the user enters a whitespace the loop terminates. Although I'd have to notify the user about this. Thanks for that code ! :)

Comment: @AyushAgarwal Does that actually work?  If you're reading using `cin >> words`, then it should never give you a string containing a space unless you've explicitly modified the input separators on the stream.

Comment: @paddy No I added `while(getline(cin, words))` instead of `while(cin >> words)`. After that I wrote `if(words==" ")` and mentioned that if the user enters an empty string then it will be considered as false input.  But after reading the code that you provided, I switched to that one and used `if(words.size()==0)` and that works good if the user enters and newline in the input by pressing 'Enter'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That link you provided regarding input problems is a little different.  It's talking about when you expect the user to enter a particular value, but you might fail to read the value (let's say it's an integer) because something else was entered.  In that case, it's good to use `getline` to retrieve a whole line of input and then parse the value out.

In your case, you're just after words.  When you read a string from a stream, it will give you all consecutive non-whitespace characters.  And, ignoring punctuation for a moment, you can call that a "word".  So when you talk about 'invalid input', I don't see what you mean.  The loop will continue to give you "words" until there are none left in the stream, at which point it will error:

```
vector<string> words;
string word;
while( cin >> word ) words.push_back(word);
```

However, if you expect the user to enter all words on one line and press enter to finish, then you need to use getline:

```
// Get all words on one line
cout << "Enter words: " << flush;
string allwords;
getline( cin, allwords );

// Parse words into a vector
vector<string> words;
string word;
istringstream iss(allwords);
while( iss >> word ) words.push_back(word);
```

Or you can do this:

```
cout << "Enter words, one per line (leave an empty line when done)\n";

vector<string> words;
string line;
while( getline(cin, line) )
{
    // Because of the word check that follows, you don't really need this...
    if( line.size() == 0 ) break;

    // Make sure it's actually a word.
    istringstream iss(line);
    string word;
    if( !(iss >> word) ) break;

    // If you want, you can check the characters and complain about non-alphabet
    // characters here...  But that's up to you.

    // Add word to vector
    words.push_back(word);
}
```